# Density of extended Mersenne numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, asymptotics, sieve-theory, mersenne-numbers

Consider the subset of odd positive integers defined and constructed as follows by these rules :

A) $1$ is in the set.

B) if $x$ is in the set , then $2x + 1$ is in the set.

C) if $x$ and $y$ are in the set then $xy$ is in the set.

I call them extended Mersenne numbers because rule A and B alone give the Mersenne numbers $2^n - 1$.

And every product of Mersenne numbers must be in the set as well.

So the set or list of extended Mersenne numbers starts like

$$1,3,7,9,15,19,21,27,31,39,43,45,49,55,57,63,79,81,87,91,93,99,...$$

The main question is how dense is this within the odd integers ?

Secondary is there an easy and efficient test to know if an odd integer is in the list ?

I assume this sequence has no name yet but I could be wrong ?

---

*** speculation ***

I see $22$ odd elements from $1$ till $99$, which is close to the number of odd primes under $99$ (that is $24$)
$$ \dfrac11 + \dfrac13 + \dfrac17 + \dfrac19 + \ldots + \ldots+\dfrac{1}{99} = 2.034980..$$

So this (subjectively I admit ) seems to imply the sequence grows quite fast.
Therefore I guess maybe an asymptotic of the form

$C* x * \ln(x)^D $

for some constants $C,D$ might be an asymptotic for the counting function.

On the other hand I suspect much sharper asymptotics can be proven.

---

---

***Background***

This comes from abstract algebra where we want a commutative latin square with units and inverses such that "Property A"

$$ x * (y * y^{-1}) = x = (x * y) * y^{-1} $$

holds for all elements $x,y$.

( if this property has a name please tell me )

and for every element $z$

$$ z^2 = 1 $$

( not the main question here, but I wonder how dropping the $z^2 = 1$ condition effects things )

The dimensions of these are then exactly these extended Mersenne numbers + $1$.

---

***edit***

corrected forgotten terms and copy lulu's conjecture :

The sequence is equal to https://oeis.org/A197625 ???

( https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu )

***edit2***

Greg Martin found counterexample 219 so lulu's conjecture is false.

Greg also conjectured that $D=0$ or $D$ goes to $0$.

It seems that Greg believes we will get close to linear, but I want to point out that the set is denser than the products of mersenne numbers.

On the other hand numbers like $63 = 3 * 21 = 2*31 + 1$ can be reached in $2$ ways so the rules have overlapping values, which could lower the density.

I would not be surprised if the density is slightly higher than the sum of 2 squares or the density of $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ which are both less than linear.

---

---

It reminds me a bit of collatz, where the rules $2x$ and $(x-1)/3$ generate all integers , or so we believe.

But these rules for the extented Mersenne numbers have no deminishing rule like  $(x-1)/3$ ( deminish because that is smaller than $x$) , which is why I believe they might not have linear density.

---

***added***

Noticed how powers of $5$ or powers of $17$ are never in the list :

$5$ and $25$ are not in.

So $125,625,…$ are not created By products.
Also $125,625,…$ are of the form $4n + 1$, so they did not come from the 2x + 1 rule either.

Similar with $17$ or other primes missing of the form $4n + 1$.

This ofcourse highly influences the density.

Also notice primes of the form $4n+1$ have to come from 2x + 1 themselves , where x must be odd !!

2 x + 1 maps 1 mod 4 to 3 mod 4, and maps 3 mod 4 to 3 mod 4 !!

So primes 1 mod 4 are a key thing here !!

---

Comment: Now posted to overflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440747/density-of-extended-mersenne-numbers without notice to either site. That's an abuse.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142858/discussion-on-question-by-mick-density-of-extended-mersenne-numbers); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: So, mick, have you made any effort to get the Bruck paper from the Albert book?